# Change dark blue background in Visual Studio 2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, colors, background, themes

The dark blue background in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE is driving me nuts. How can I change the background to a slate silver color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change background colour for Visual Studio Code Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187837/change-background-colour-for-visual-studio-code-editor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that in Tools / Options and then Environment / Fonts And Colors and there is a setting for background color.

Or even better you can choose from predefined styles at http://studiostyl.es/, these style setting works for Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 for all versions, including the express : 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/29/download-and-share-visual-studio-color-schemes.aspx

Comment: I can't find an appropriate setting.  There are plenty of settings to do with the background color of editor (e.g. black on white) and output windows, but nothing to set the dark blue background of the VS 2010 IDE itself.  I've gone through all the "show settings for" options, as well.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

I use this one:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378?SRC=VSIDE

It will add a 'Theme' menu to the tool bar where you can change the colour scheme to a pre-set one, or define your own.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the Express Edition. All I want to be able to do is change the background color.

Answer (score 1):

there is a site called https://studiostyl.es it contains a some of nice themes
[image: site image]

download a theme you like

then  go to tools>options>Environment>import and export setting

then you will see a textbox for team setting file

finally, put the path of your downloaded setting file, then press ok

[image: theme image]