# Change the background of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I have researched a long time for a way to change the background of Visual Studio to a image, just like a wallpaper of desktop.

Is there a add-in, extension or a little trick can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187837/change-background-colour-for-visual-studio-code-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ClaudiaIDE](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ba50f8d-f30c-4e33-ab19-bfd9f56eb817) : This free extension change the background image of editor.
Works for VS 2012-13.

[VSEditorBackgroundChangerExtension](https://github.com/nategreenwood/VSEditorBackgroundChangerExtension) : A Visual Studio 2012 IDE extension which allows for easily adding a background image or watermark to liven up your text editors.

Let us know if they works well!